# Typeclasses 101: GHC too "eager" to derive instance?

Tags: haskell, instances

Given the following code:

```
class C a where
  foo :: a -> a

f :: (C a) => a -> a
f = id

p :: (C a) => (a -> a) -> a -> a
p g = foo . g
```

Now, if I try to invoke p f, GHC complains:

```
> p f
No instance for (C a0) arising from a use of `p'
In the expression: p f
In an equation for `it': it = p f
```

I find that somewhat surprising, since f only accepts an "a" which has to be an instance of the typeclass C. What is the reason?

Edit: I know I did not define any instance for C but shouldn't the "proper" response be:

```
p f :: (C a) => a -> a
```

Comment: `p f :: (C a) => a -> a` is the proper response to `:t p f`, but you entered `p f`.

Comment: The question that GHCi is asking is, *"I know it's an instance of `C`, but which instance is it? Otherwise, I can't determine if I can `show` it or not."*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you put a plain expression into ghci, it is basically trying to `print` it, so

```
> p f
```

is approximately the same as having the following in a file

```
main :: IO ()
main = print $ p f
```

As you pointed out, `p f :: (C a) => a -> a`. In order to `print $ p f` GHC needs to evaluate `p f`. GHC cannot evaluate a value with a type class context without choosing a dictionary to pass in. To do so, it needs to find a `C a` instance for all `a`, which doesn't exit. It also needs to find a `Show` instance for `a -> a`. The inability to find either of these results in two errors

```
No instance for (Show (a -> a)) arising from a use of `print'
No instance for (C a) arising from a use of `p'
```

Answer (score 4):

It's the dreaded [monomorphism restriction](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monomorphism_restriction) in action. By default, GHC doesn't allow us to have top-level value definitions without type annotations if the inferred type has a class constraint. You can remedy the situation by

a.) Turning the restriction off by adding `{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}` to the top of your source.

b.) Adding type annotations to affected top-level bindings:

```
foo :: C a => a -> a
foo = p f
```

c.) Expanding function definitions (if possible):

```
foo x = p f x
```

Comment: Even disabling the monomorphism restriction with `:set -XNoMonomorphismRestriction` entering the naked expression `p f` into ghci results in the error `No instance for (C c0) ...`.

Comment: I think that's an artifact arising from GHCi-7.8 trying to print it. GHCi-7.10 doesn't give that error message at all (instead it throws `No instance for Show...`).

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with printing (``p f `seq` ()`` also gives an error), and it's not really the MR either. It's something much more basic: GHC cannot *evaluate* a value with a type class context without choosing a dictionary to pass in. In particular, no matter how you slice it, it doesn't know *which* type's `foo` to use here.